# Retorno de String

Tags: string, return, golang

Estou tentando retornar uma `String` formata em uma função, porem ocorre erro n definido.

```
func descreve(x, y int) string{
    total := soma(x, y)
    return "%d + %d = %d", x, y, total
}
```

Não quero usar apenas um `Println()` pra aprender a retornar `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro indefinido é outro problema porque você não definiu a função de está usando. O problema real relatado na pergunta é que está retornando vários valores em vez de fazer uma formatação, que é o que está dizendo que deseja. Não é tirar o `Printf()` que vai funcionar, essa função faz a formatação por você quando vai imprimir, mas sem nada não formata magicamente, alguma função precisa ser chamada para formatar o dado.

Veja a [documentação de `Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#example_Sprintf).

```
package main
import "fmt"

func descreve(x, y int) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d + %d = %d", x, y, x + y)
}

func main(){
    fmt.Printf(descreve(1, 2))
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/byEytO). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vierzvvr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Format.go).